# CSS Function Issue with Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some CSS code that executes on page load and when a user clicks a checkbox. The code hides the rows of the table except the header when checkbox is clicked. I have some additional code that hides those rows on page load. I have two tables in the code here and on page load both tables are correctly hidden. If user clicks first table checkbox it reveals the first table correctly. The second table which is also hidden (correctly) on page load cannot be un-hidden by clicking its checkbox. Yet the code for the two appears to me to be correct.

Why can't the second table be un-hidden based on the checkbox?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#HideValidationRows').change(function() {
      if (!this.checked)
        $('.AllValidationRows').fadeOut(300);
      else
        $('.AllValidationRows').fadeIn(300);
    });
    $('#HideValidationRows').trigger('change');

    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent('td').next('td').css("font-weight", "bold")(this).parent('td').next('td').css("color:", "red");

      } else {
        $(this).parent('td').next('td').css("font-weight", "normal");

      }
    });

  });
</script>
<table 900px="" border="1" style="width: 900px; height: 40px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 40px;">
      <td style="width: 40px; background-color: #bdac73; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="HideValidationRows" /></td>
      <td style="height: 23px; background-color: #bdac73; width: 478px;" colspan="2"><span style="color: #000000;"> <strong> &nbsp; Verification, Validation &amp; Qualification</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px; text-align: center" td="">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 17px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;IQ/OQ/PQ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px; text-align: center;" td="">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Design Verification</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px; text-align: center;" td="">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 22px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Design Validation</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 21px; text-align: center;" td="">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Process Validation</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px; text-align: center;" td="">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Labels Verification</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px; text-align: center;" td="">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Non-Current DPD Authority &amp; Derivative Dataset Archive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px; text-align: center;" td="">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;First Article Inspection Report</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
<!-- END VERIFICATION, VALIDATION & QUALIFICATION PARAMETERS SECTION OF ECN-->


<!-- BEGIN SUPPLIERS & MATERIAL OF THE ECN-->
<!-- THIS SECTION HAS THE SUPPLIERS & MATERIAL PARAMETERS OF THE ECN-->
<script>
  <!-- HIDES/SHOWS SUPPLIERS & MATERIAL SECTION OF THE ECN-->
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#HideAllSupplierRows').change(function() {
      if (!this.checked)
        $('.AllSupplierRows').fadeOut(300);
      else
        $('.AllSupplierRows').fadeIn(300);
    });
    $('#HideAllSupplierRows').trigger('change');
  });
</script>

<table border="1" style="width: 900px; height: 40px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 20px;">
      <td style="width: 40px; background-color: #11d6d0; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="HideAllSupplierRows" /></td>
      <td style="height: 23px; background-color: #11d6d0;" width: 478px; colspan="2"><span style="color: #000000;"> <strong> Suppliers &amp; Material</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 20px;" class="AllSupplierRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px; text-align: center" td="">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Lead Times / Material Planning</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 20px;" class="AllSupplierRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px; text-align: center" td="">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Order Parts</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 20px;" class="AllSupplierRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px; text-align: center" td="">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Supplier Qualifications</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missing `$` on line 11, that is at:

```
(this).parent('td').next('td').css("color:","red");
```

Here's working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50pamhxr/2/

So the full first script should be:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#HideValidationRows').change(function() {
            if (!this.checked)
                $('.AllValidationRows').fadeOut(300);
            else
                $('.AllValidationRows').fadeIn(300);
        });
        $('#HideValidationRows').trigger('change');

        $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).parent('td').next('td').css({"font-weight": "bold", "color": "red"});
            } else {
                $(this).parent('td').next('td').css("font-weight", "normal");

            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: That seemed to have fixed the hide/reveal function. Oddly font color change is not working, but thank you for the catch!

Comment: Oh don't remember that was part of your question but np here's new jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/50pamhxr/2/  the color fix is on line 13. Cheers!

Comment: Oh so close! I see the colon is outside the double quotes. Thanks very much!